# delete rows of one csv based on another csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, jupyter-notebook

So I have two csv files,

file1:
1,a,t
2,b,f
3,c,t
4,d,t
5,e,f

file2:
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
6,f
7,g
8,h
9,i
10,j

I want to merge them and have a file that looks something like this:

1,a,t
2,b,f
3,c,t
4,d,t
5,e,f
6,f
7,g
8,h
9,i
10,j

basically I want to rewrite identical file 2 rows with the file 1 rows.

im also new to coding pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer join to merge these two dataframes.

`df1.merge(df2, "outer", on = ["firstCol", "secondCol"])`

For detailed information you can check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)